# Not able to see Push to AzureDevOps service in sync option Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

I am planning to use Azure Devops for code repository. I was able to add code to Git repository as you can see in below screenshot (I have a master branch). I am trying to push this to Azure Devops but while click on sync from Team Explorer, I am not able to see those three options:

- Publish to GitHub
- Push to Azure Devops service
- Push to Remote Repository

Am I missing something? I really need to push this git repo to Azure Devops. I have already created a project in Azure Devops to push into that. Please help.

[image]

Comment: What remotes do you have in your repository?